# Building multiple apks from on android app source

Tags: android, eclipse, build, apk

The application reads a key from a file to hit production vs test server.
I want to create a test apk build that will pick test key and second build apk for release that will pick the production key

I am currently building app using eclipse

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983492/build-multiple-test-prod-versions-of-android-apks-in-eclipse?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it is related with what you mention, but it sounds to me like you could perhaps include such functionality through the usage of [License Verification Library (LVL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html), consequently having a single app and still being able to deal with the key issues.
Hope that helps.